# Make one flex-item take more height than the others after they wrap

Tags: html, css

I have a hero section divided in two parts. One is mainly decorative and the other has more text and elements. I want to have it divided in two columns when the screen is wide enough and wrap when the screen gets too small. So far I have accomplished this. However once the items wrap they both use 50% of the parent's height. I want one of them to shrink to the size of it's elements while the other grows to use the reminder of the parent height.
Here is a working example:

```css
.hero {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
height: 500px;
}
.hero .item {
  flex-basis: 40%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

/*PURELY DECORATIVE*/
.hero {
  background-color: hsla(0, 100%, 50%, 0.5);
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px dotted red;
}
.item1 {
  background-color: hsla(120, 100%, 50%, 0.5);
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px dotted green;
}
.item2 {
  background-color: hsla(240, 100%, 50%, 0.5);
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
    <div class="item item1">Item1. Should be short when wrapped</div>
    <div class="item item2">Item2. Should take all available height when wrapped.</div>
</section>
```

The closest I've got to a solution, whithout adding a media query, is adding the `align-content: flex-start` property to the flex container and then give `height: 100%` to the desired item. However this causes overflow once the items wrap.

Comment: If you really don't wanna use grid you can solve with a media query that changes flex direction when width is less than 600px

Answer (score 1):

You can try with CSS grid

```css
.hero {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(300px,100%), 40%));
  grid-template-rows: auto; /* first row auto */
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr; /* when there is a second row it will take the remaining space */
  height: 500px;
}


/*PURELY DECORATIVE*/
.hero {
  background-color: hsla(0, 100%, 50%, 0.5);
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px dotted red;
}

.item1 {
  background-color: hsla(120, 100%, 50%, 0.5);
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px dotted green;
}

.item2 {
  background-color: hsla(240, 100%, 50%, 0.5);
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="item item1">Item1. Should be short when wrapped</div>
  <div class="item item2">Item2. Should take all available height when wrapped.</div>
</section>
```